# What does setting Unrestricted = false on PrincipalPermission supposed to do?

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I am doing some maintenance on a 10 year old ASP.net web-forms application. It has a business layer that has its methods protected by `System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermissionAttribute`, like this:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true, Role = "2,3", Unrestricted = true)]
public void Foo(int bar)
```

A custom IIdentity and IPrincipal are used. The custom principal implements  `bool IsInRole(string role)` and interprets the role parameter as a comma-separated list of roles to check against.

I assume this once all worked just fine, but, currently, the `IsInRole` method is never called.

Of course, my attention was drawn towards the *unrestricted*-property. [The MSDN documentation does not clarify a lot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityattribute.unrestricted.aspx). I just tried with `unrestricted = false` and lo and behold, the validation sprang to live.

As far a I can trace back the code, the parameter *unrestricted* has always been passed as true. So, I am hesitating to just changes this to false everywhere.

Does this property really has the effect of saying:

> "Hey, I am declaring permissions here, but actually, never mind and just go ahead."

Or is is something more subtle?

Answer (score 1):

It's not more subtle.

Setting `Unrestricted = true` means it will match any principal, and so setting the `Authenticated` and `Role` properties is pointless, because once the framework sees `Unrestricted = true`, it will always set `Authenticated = true` and `Role = null` and the demand will always succeed, regardless of the the principal.

So, it sounds to me like setting it to false (or simply removing it from the attribute altogether) is indeed likely what you want to do.